# How do I find/define a projection that gives me exact relative positions inside an area?

Tags: coordinate-system, gis-principle

Assuming that a set of positions are all inside a 5km square area:
How do I find/define a projection to reproject the positions, so that the relative positions between the now reprojected positions are exact?

This would mean that for **any** pair of objects inside that 5km square area; If I do `distance = obj1.EastingNorthing - obj2.EastingNorthing` I will get a `distance` vector whose value has less than 1cm of error, in relation to the true distance.

Is there a single projection that I can use globally?
Does it have to be a different projection for each square? How do I build it?

Comment: What are you trying to render your 3D scene with?  Is it a web map or something?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "projection".  If you mean "coordinate reference" (projection plus parameters), then of course the answer is "No."  If you're willing to create locally appropriate parameters, then multiple projections are available (depending on the definition of "anywhere" (the need for polar mapping).

Comment: I think knowing some more about what you are trying to accomplish would help.  Can you give an idea of what your final goal is, in a little more detail?

Comment: EPSG:3857 will **NOT** give you true distances. Only on the equator the web mercator distances in x and y are correct.

Comment: Since you're doing 3D rendering, why not use 3D coordinates for objects on the earth? That won't require any projection at all.

Comment: @Vince Yes, I probably mean coordinate reference. I'm not 100% familiar with the terminology.

Comment: @Tangnar Why is it important? I'm using a normal 3D engine.

Comment: @Vince "If you're willing to create locally appropriate parameters, then multiple projections are available (depending on the definition of "anywhere" (the need for polar mapping)." How so?

Comment: @AndreJ How can I have true X and Y then?

Comment: If you build a local transverse mercator CRS where lat_0 and lon_0 is in the center of your scene, you will have true distances within 5 kilometers.

Comment: @AndreJ that might be what I'm looking for. Can you make it into a complete answer?

Comment: Unfortuantely, the question is on hold, so I can not insert an answer. You can edit your question to be more specific, and ask the mod's for reopening.

Comment: @AndreJ I rewrote the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build a local transverse mercator CRS where lon_0 and lat_0 is in the center of your scene, you will have true distances within 5 kilometers:

```
+proj=tmerc +lon_0=7 +lat_0=51 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
```

It should work in the ARCGIS world just the same.